# Multiple events firing on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a button below to the textarea and on the click on this button, reading the textarea value and downloading into csv. Below is the code snippet.

Whenever, I'm clicking on Export, the downloads increasing with increasing clicks i.e. on first click, one file is downloaded, second click-two files downloaded, third click-three files downloaded and so on...

```
$(document).on('click', '#id_export_button', function() {       
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        with (a) {
            href = 'data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa($('textarea')[0].value);
            download = 'File.csv';
        }
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);       
    });

$("textarea")[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="localCreatedDIV" style="width:100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row; margin-top: 15px; justify-content: space-between"><div id="localCreatedDIVSecond" style=""><button id="id_export_button">Export</button></div></div>');`
```

Comment: How many times do you call the `on()` method to attach the event?

Comment: Off topic: please review [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

Comment: Your code, *as provided*, [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf9cx3w2/).  As noted above, it looks like you're re-calling the `$(document).on('click',` multiple times, most likely from within the/a click handler itself (which is why it increases on each click).  Without see all of your (relevant) code, this is only a guess.   As you can see from the fiddle above, you only get 1 file each time you click.

Comment: Either that or you're simply misunderstanding what's being downloaded when/why you get `File (3).csv`

Comment: Please include a [mcve] - but at the least please include a screenshot of it downloading multiple files?